# Unmarshalling works incorrectly: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Got an exception

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element 
(uri:"", local:"ConnectorCommandType")
```

trying to unmarshall xml, shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <ConnectorCommandType> ........ </ConnectorCommandType>
```

The exception basically says that element  is not found in jaxb context. But debugging shows that this class is present and known in current jaxb context. The class ConnectorCommandType was generated from xsd xml as `<xs:complexType>` element.

Could there be an error in the xsd?

Has anyone faced with problem like that? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on the answer to the following question:

*Is there an `@XmlRootElement(name="ConnectorCommandType")` annotation on the `ConnectorCommandType` class, or an `@XmlElementDecl(name="ConnectorCommandType")` on a create method in the `ObjectFactory` class?*

**If the answer is YES**

Is there a `package-info` in your generated model?  It appears as though your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is expecting a namespace qualified document.  Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ConnectorCommandType xmlns="YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE">
     ........ 
</ConnectorCommandType>
```

For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

**If the answer is NO**

If the `ConnectorCommandType` element is not associated with a class, then you will need to
use one of the unmarshal methods that takes a class parameter.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: Thak you for help. There was my mistake: in order to use <xs:complexType> elements as entities during unmarshalling they also should be defined as <xs:element> with related complex type elements.